# Target a specific cell background color in a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

With vuejs I fill a table with some data with this code :

```
<tr v-for="droit in listedroit">
 <td>{{ droit.id_u }}</td>
 <td>{{ droit.role }}</td>
 <td>{{ droit.id_e }}</td>
 <td>{{ droit.droits }}</td>
 <td v-bind:style="{ 'background-color': statusColor }">STATUS</td>
</tr>
```

statusColor is computed in my app.js and returned to the template.
Some rows need a red cell, others a green one (I check if the rights are RO(green) or RW(red)).

The problem is I failed to target a specific cell of a row, and if I set statusColor to 'red', the whole column is red.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This should be easy to implement. Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method instead of a computed property

```
<template>
  <tr v-for="droit in listedroit">
    <td>{{ droit.id_u }}</td>
    <td>{{ droit.role }}</td>
    <td>{{ droit.id_e }}</td>
    <td>{{ droit.droits }}</td>
    <td v-bind:style="{ 'background-color': statusColor(droit.rights) }">STATUS</td>
   </tr>
</template>
```

---

```
export default{
  methods: {
    statusColor(rights){
      if(rights === 'RO'){ 
        return 'green'; 
      } else { 
        return 'red'; 
      }
    }
  }
}
```